# Move class structure tab in Android Studio below Project files

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way for the Structure tab in Android Studio to appear under your project files like in PHPStorm? As it stands now, it appears on the side as shown below.

**PHPStorm**

[image]

**Android Studio 3.1.2**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and Drop the tab Structure and put it on the bottom left.

[image: Drag and Drop]

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!